# linear transformation of matricies

Tags: matrices

given that X is an n × p matrix with linearly independent columns.

And X∗ = XA, where A is an invertible p × p matrix.

Show that: $$X^*{({X^*}^TX^*)^-}^1{X^*}^T = X{(X^TX)^-}^1X^T$$

attempt:

$$X^*{({X^*}^TX^*)^-}^1{X^*}^T = XA{(XA^TXA)^-}^1XA^T$$

can I just multiply it by the inverse of A?

Comment: Note that $(X^{*})^{T} = (XA)^{T} = A^{T}X^{T}$ which differs from what you wrote. Since $A$ is stated to be invertible, you can certainly use $A^{-1}$.

Comment: yes i forgot about that bit $$XA{(X^TA^TXA)^-}^1X^TA^T$$ now multiplying by $${A^-}^1$$ would give $$X{(X^TA^TXA)^-}^1X^TA^T$$ where would i go from here?